# BlackBerry Webworks Scrolling Beyond Width or Height

Tags: jquery, html, css, blackberry-webworks

The basic layout of the mobile app is:

The html layout:

```
<div id="title">Title</div>
<div id="tabs">Some tabs</div>
<div id="container" x-blackberry-focusable="true">
<div id="contents" style="width: "1000px;" height: "1000px;">
<div x-blackberry-focusable="true" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseout="noHighlight(this)">I am some content">
 . 
 .
 .
<div x-blackberry-focusable="true" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseout="noHighlight(this)">I am some content"> 
</div>
</div>
```

The css code:

```
#title
{
   height: 50px;
}
#tabs
{
   height: 40px;
}
#container
{
   overflow: auto;
}
```

I set the width and height of the  using jQuery to detect the width and height of the mobile screen so it fits different version of BlackBerry phone. jQuery is also used to detect width for div#title, div#tabs and div#container.Finally the height of div#container is calculated by subtracting the screen height with div#title and div#tabs height.

The contents inside div#container will always be bigger than the div#container height or width. For example on Torch 9800 the screen is 360x480 div#container would be 360x390 then anything inside would be bigger than div#container.

Even though I set div#container overflow: auto, when I use trackpad or trackball to scroll the contents inside div#container, it will never get past the div#container width or height even though the inner container is bigger than div#container.

Can anyone please help me. I have stuck for weeks and really at lost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
  #container{
      overflow: scroll;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
```

**note:** If container/contents has position properties (absolute or relative) it won't work properly. BB OS6 and above uses webkit.